# Search Inputted Text For Bad Words Defined In Array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I want to create a little script which will take in the user's inputted text and then search the text for bad words. The bad words are defined in an array. As far as I get it, I should have the following process:

1. Get input from the user - this part is easy, use the $_POST array
2. Convert the inputted string into an array - make use of the explode() function
3. Create 2 for loops, 1 outer for loop and 1 inner for loop. Inside the inner for loop, create an if statement that will check for bad words.

I want each time a bad word is found, it will increment the variable which will count the total number of bad words.

I manage to code all this, but my counter isn't working as it should, it gives me 0.

Here is the code below:

```
<?php
$badWordCounter = 0;
$badWords = array("bitch", "hoe", "slut", "motherfucker", "fuck", "ass", "cunt");
$inputedText =  $_POST['inputText'];

$inputedText_ToProcess = strtolower($inputedText);

$inputedText_ToProcess = explode(" ", $inputedText_ToProcess);

$outerLoop = sizeof($inputedText_ToProcess);
$innerLoop = sizeof($badWords);

for ($a = 0; $a < $outerLoop ; $a++)
{
    for ($b = 0; $b < $innerLoop; $b++)
    {
        if ($badWords[$b] == $inputedText_ToProcess[$a])
        {
            $badwordCounter = $badWordCounter + 1;
        }
    }
}

echo "<p>The Total Number of Bad Words Detected In The Text: $badWordCounter</p>";
echo "The entered text string is: $inputedText";

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot a capital on Word in your variable badWordCounter when incrementing it.

It should read:

```
$badWordCounter = $badWordCounter + 1;
```

Instead of:

```
$badwordCounter = $badWordCounter + 1;
```

You could have also used `$badWordCounter++;`

Since everyone is posting additional code that doesn't work, I thought I would offer a solution that is simpler and works with punctuation:

```
$badWords = array("bitch", "hoe", "slut", "motherfucker", "fuck", "ass", "cunt");
preg_match_all("/".implode('|', $badWords)."/i", $_POST['inputText'], $badWordCounter);

echo '<p>The Total Number of Bad Words Detected In The Text: '.count($badWordCounter[0]).'</p>';
echo 'The entered text string is: '.$_POST['inputText'];
```

Comment: *"Since everyone is posting additional code that doesn't work, I thought I would offer a solution that is simpler and works with punctuation:"* - Is that the full code that OP is to use, or is it to be added on to what OP posted?

Comment: Ok. Well, I'm just testing everyone's code today. Yours will produce "The Total Number of Bad Words Detected In The Text: Array". I tried fixing it myself, but with no success.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Copy / Paste it again, I just tested it and it works well.

Comment: +1 Yep, and it even takes the punctuation into account. I'd say this is the better answer.

Answer (score 1):

Watch the case of your variables:

$bad**w**ordCounter = $badWordCounter + 1;

btw the nested loops are over-complicated, a cleaner example:

```
<?php

$_POST['inputText'] = 'come on you ass hole!'; // hardcoded for testing

$badwordCounter = 0;
$badWords = array("bitch", "hoe", "slut", "motherfucker", "fuck", "ass", "cunt");
$inputedText =  $_POST['inputText'];

$inputedText_ToProcess = strtolower($inputedText);
$inputedText_ToProcess = explode(" ", $inputedText_ToProcess);

// Iterate through each word
foreach ($inputedText_ToProcess as $word) {
    // If that word exists in the badWords array
    if (in_array($word, $badWords)) {
        $badwordCounter++;
    }
}

echo "<p>The Total Number of Bad Words Detected In The Text: $badwordCounter</p>";
echo "The entered text string is: $inputedText";
```

Comment: This works, however it won't count `cunt!` if post is `come on you ass hole cunt!`

Comment: I just made this based on your original logic. You should remove all punctuations before scanning for bad words.

Comment: I'm not the OP. Was a sidenote.

Comment: Hoops sorry lol. The reason is that the last piece of the exploded array is "cunt!". So the OP should remove all punctuations before scanning for bad words.

Comment: Indeed, it's an option.

Comment: hey, you need additional logic (which is NOT asked in your original question) to check against plurals. The simplest way is to put the plural forms into the badwords array.

Answer (score 1):

You can use foreach for going through the whole array. Easier than a 'for' loop. Also, there's a function called in_array, which checks if the string given as the first parameter is in the array given as the second parameter. So this one should work:

```
<?php
$badWordCounter = 0;
$badWords = array("bitch", "hoe", "slut", "motherfucker", "fuck", "ass", "cunt");
$inputedText =  $_POST['inputText'];
$inputedText_ToProcess = explode(" ", $inputedText);

foreach ($inputedText_ToProcess as $value) {
  if (in_array(strtolower($value), $badWords)) {
    $badWordCounter++;
  }
}

echo "<p>The Total Number of Bad Words Detected In The Text: " . $badWordCounter . "</p>";
echo "The entered text string is: " . $inputedText;

?>
```

Comment: Sidenote: This will cause a parse error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{'...` for `if (in_array(strtolower($value), $badWords) {`

Comment: True. I was missing a closing parenthesis.